# Insert javascript in Robotium

Tags: javascript, robotium

I am trying to create test for an Android map app, but while running the test GPS doesnot get the current location somehow. To bypass, I need to insert some javascript to be able to do so.
Can somebody please tell me how to insert a javascript code in a robotium script?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite easy:

```
private void injectJavaScriptCode(final WebView webView, final String code) {
    solo.getCurrentActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:" + code);
        }
    });
}
```